# conflicting between cakephp auth login function and facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm beginner in cakephp and I'm trying to use the Facebook php sdk
but i get conflict between cakephp auth login function and facebook sdk calling

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '123456789',
    'secret' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'cookie' => true
));
$fbuserid = $facebook->getUser();
if ($fbuserid) {
    try {
        $Uinfo = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $fbuserid = null;
    }
}
// some code here
$this->Auth->login($userdata);
```

this code works perfectly only if i removing facebook class calling

Comment: Try to describe your problem better. "I get a conflict" isn't very helpful. Also where does `$userdata` come from.

Comment: I developed a few fb apps with cakephp, and in my experience it's sometimes easier to drop `Auth` and just check `$facebook->getUser()` in `AppController`.

Comment: Thanks for replies,
i cut the facebook calling code from function,
and put it in beforefilter() function,
this work fine

Comment: Hey thanks Mostafa, that worked for me :) I was also facing the same issue. After moving the Facebook object creation code to the AppControllers Beforefiler it start working fine.

Comment: This one worked for me. What is the issue with Facebook SDK and CakePHP's Auth?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on in the Facebook SDK. There is a great plugin written for CakePHP by WebTechNick over on GitHub. Maybe this will help you so you are not reinventing the wheel. Check it out here:

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

there is also facebook authenticate plugin:
https://github.com/MozMorris/FacebookAuthenticate-CakePhp-Authentication-Handler